# Не полный apk после сборки через Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

После сборки apk, открыв его через менеджер архивов, внутри не обнаружил папку с классами. Как можно исправить?

Comment: Возможно у вас оно собрано не целиком, а через `apply changes`. Попробуйте собрать через `build` команду. Или расскажите как именно вы собирали APK

Comment: @woesss Спасибо, вы правы

Comment: @woesss Можете опубликовать ответ, чтобы я могла его отметить как правильный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Папок с классами в APK быть и не должно - все java-классы конвертируются в DEX-формат и собираются в один или несколько файлов `classes.dex`. В случае с Котлин, классы сначала 
конвертируются в java и дальше тоже самое в DEX.

Их содержимое можно увидеть в студии через меню `Build->Analize APK...` или открыв APK из окошка `Project`, или просто перетащить мышью в окно студии из проводника.
Гайд по теме: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer

Answer (score 0):

В меню Android Studio: `Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s)`